# How to prove Gauss's identities on the action of the theta operator $f' = x\frac{df}{dx}$ on Jacobi theta functions?

Tags: ho.history-overview, theta-functions

(I have previously posted this question on mathstackexchange, but after getting no response there I decided to ask it again here. Here is a link to [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499146/how-to-prove-gausss-identities-on-the-action-of-the-operator-f-x-fracdfd) there, so if this question is not appropriate here than I'll be glad if someone will help there.)

P.444-445 of volume 3 of Gauss's Nachlass, in which Gauss wrote down an identity for the infinite series of $\vartheta^4_3(x)$ (this identity is the essence of Jacobi's four squares theorem), include several differential equations which, together with his identity for $\mathbb{log}(\vartheta^4_3(x))$ (which is dicussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497268/how-to-prove-an-identity-of-gauss-for-the-logarithm-of-jacobi-theta-function/4498269#4498269)), apparently enabled him to derive the identities for $\vartheta^4_2(x),\vartheta^4_3(x),\vartheta^4_4(x)$. I believe the missing piece in the puzzle of answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576675/did-gauss-know-jacobis-four-squares-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1) is to understand the origin of these differential equations. I will describe them right now.

Denote $\vartheta_2(x),\vartheta_3(x),\vartheta_4(x)$ as $r,p,q$ respectively. Denote also $t=\frac{1}{p^2},u=\frac{1}{q^2}$. Then define the following mathematical operator: $t' = x\frac{dt} {dx}$ (although the $'$ symbol, this operator is not derivative). Then I would like to know how to prove the following identities:

$$\frac{u}{t}-\frac{t}{u}=2(tu'-ut')=-4u^3t'' = 4t^3u''$$
$$\frac{t'''}{t''}+3\frac{t'}{t}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^4}+16\frac{t''}{t}}.$$
The significance of the first equation can be explained along the following line:
$$\frac{u}{t}-\frac{t}{u}=2(tu'-ut')\implies \frac{p^2}{q^2}-\frac{q^2}{p^2}=2x(t\frac{du}{dx}-u\frac{dt}{dx})\implies p^4-q^4 = 2p^2q^2x(t\frac{du}{dx}-u\frac{dt}{dx})\implies r^4 = \frac{2x}{tu}(t\frac{du}{dx}-u\frac{dt}{dx}) \implies r^4 = 2x(\frac{\frac{du}{dx}}{u}-\frac{\frac{dt}{dx}}{t}) \implies r^4 = 4x(\frac{d\mathbb{log}(\frac{p}{q})}{dx})$$,
so this identity connects $r^4$ with the logarithmic derivatives of $p,q$; therefore, the first equation alone already enables to derive the expansion of $r^4$ as a linear combination of Lambert series (but I don't know how to prove this differential equation). Note also that since the series for $r^4$ consists only of odd powers and $q(x)=p(-x)$, the series expansion of $r^4$ allows to find the odd part of the series for $p^4,q^4$.

I will have much appreciation for an answer that will explain the principle behind such identities on theta functions (identities which involve the $'$ operator).

**Update:**

After making some search I found out that the operator which Gauss used here is well known and is called "[Theta operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_operator)". It has a useful property that its eigenfunctions are simply monomials in $x$.

Comment: A comment: the theta operator is simply the operator which sends $\ln(x)^n \rightarrow n\ln(x)^{n-1}$ so all this is in a certain sense just exploring logarithmic Taylor series and reasoning about when logarithmic series expansions hold. This also explains your monomial eigenfunction property at the end since $e^{\ln(x)} = x$

Comment: Also can you clarify the question, what exactly do you mean by: “Then I would like to know on what grounds the following identities hold:”… as in over which subsets of the complex plane are these true? Or just are you looking for a proof/intuition? if just a proof you can probably try to expand the logarithmic Laurent series of both sides of the equation and check that they are equal telling you that wherever those series converge said expressions will match

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal - I am looking for proof/intuition, with emphasis on explanation of the main idea behind the use of theta operator for such developments. Also, I read that this operator is sometimes nicknamed "Ramanujan operator" because Ramanujan used it a lot in his work.